# Custom table order, by certain ids then desc

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to write something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id 0, 1 DESC
```

So I would be able to order the results by id from the last one to the first one, while having the first 2 stay still.

So if I have this table (just an example) :

```
id   lucky_number
0         10
1         20
2         30
3         40
4         50
5         60
```

I would get this result back :

```
id   lucky_number
0         10
1         20
5         60
4         50
3         40
2         30
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You might also take a look at FIELD()

Comment: @Strawberry thank you for the hint, I posted an answer using that function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, you can add a variable to your `ORDER BY` which is 1 for id = 0 or 1 and order by that descending, then order by `id`, but using `-id` when `id` isn't 0 or 1 to make those values sort descending:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
ORDER BY id IN (0,1) DESC, CASE WHEN id IN (0,1) THEN id ELSE -id END;
```

Output:

```
id  lucky_number
0   10
1   20
5   60
4   50
3   40
2   30
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cd4qmQrofSbjrdwPCFZPTw/0)

Comment: Could you kindly post a doc reference to the minus symbol in SQL?

Comment: @Elshobokshy https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_minus

Answer (score 1):

I found another way of doing it using `FIELD()` :

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
ORDER BY FIELD(id,1,0) DESC, id DESC
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cd4qmQrofSbjrdwPCFZPTw/2)

Comment: That's a clever solution. I'll have to remember it for future use.